# Serving embeded static files with Nancy 2.0 (clinteastwood)

Tags: c#, .net-core, nancy, kestrel-http-server

I'm trying to serve static assets in the folder `assets` via Nancy. Here's the code that I am using in the Bootstrapper:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
{
    var assets = EmbeddedStaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory(
        "/assets", GetType().Assembly);
    nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(assets);
    base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
}
```

I have marked the file `(project root)/assets/test.css` as an embedded resource. Yet when I start up the server and visit `localhost:5000/assets/test.css` I get a 404 error.

It should be noted that I'm running dotnet core 2.0-preview2-final on OS X Sierra.

Comment: Try to remane assets to Content and remove the code

Comment: I'm still not able to access the file (either through `/test.css` or `/Content/test.css`). Please note the title in that I am wishing to embed the static resources.

Comment: I had the same issue and the fast way is to add the resource to the broker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with @inqonsole (Kevin Boon) in the Nancy Slack channel, he had me try out a project that worked on his machine which is a different platform. Still didn't work. Probably a bug in Nancy-Embedded (I'll file it on their Github). He suggested using Kestrel instead to serve the embedded files. This is in the Startup class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {

        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Startup).Assembly, typeof(Startup).Namespace + ".assets"),
             RequestPath = new PathString("/assets")
        });

    }
```

You'll need to have the packages `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles` and `Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded` from NuGet in your project.

For the sake of completeness (for other dotnet core noobs like me), here's the Main function of Program.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IWebHost webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
        webHost.Run();
    }
```